# Can slideup() function be used to slide up a page when clicked on some input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement slideup functionality to a page in a mobile JQuery design. Like when some one clicks on the inputype  then a textarea is getting opened but I want the whole page to slide up and that textarea should be centered in the screen.

Please see [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbFW8/2/) of what I have done. I want the page to slide up a little.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" style="color:#006699 !important">

<h4>Estoy interesado(a) En la propiedad, </h4>

    <input id="radio-choice-1" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">favor de enviarme más información</label>
    <input id="radio-choice-2" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label for="radio-choice-2">deseo visitarla</label>
    <input id="radio-choice-3" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="3" />
    <label for="radio-choice-3">envieme fotos</label>
    <input id="radio-choice-4" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="4" />
    <label for="radio-choice-4">envieme más fotos</label>
</fieldset>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
<a data-rel="back" href="#pageone" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-theme="c" title="Close">Cancelar</a>

<div style="float: right; margin-right: -10px;">
    <input class="me" data-theme="c" data-role="button" data-inline="true" type="submit" data-icon="search" id="im_send_message" name="im_send_message" value="Enviar" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("#textarea").hide();
    $("[name=opcmessage]").on("change", function () {
//Added this line to slide up 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:300}, 'slow');
        var text = $(this).closest("div").find("label").text();
        var str = "Estoy interesado(a) en la propiedad,";
        var text = str.concat(text);
        $("#textarea").text(text).show();
        $(".me").closest("div").removeClass("ui-icon-search").addClass("ui-icon-check");

    });
});
```

Just following line to the click event and it works

```
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:300}, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("#textarea").slideUp();
    $("[name=opcmessage]").on("change", function () {
        var text = $(this).closest("div").find("label").text();
        var str = "Estoy interesado(a) en la propiedad,";
        var text = str.concat(text);
        $("#textarea").text(text).slideDown();
        $(".me").closest("div").removeClass("ui-icon-search").addClass("ui-icon-check");
    });
});
```

User 'slideUp/slideDown' instead of 'hide/show'

Comment: Oh you did not understood my question . Now I have done it this is the way I did have a look $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:300}, 'slow'); I just addeed one more line of code to it and it works fine